# How to specify top N rows matching criteria?

Tags: dataset, sql-server-2008

I am using SSMS 2008 and I have create a dataset with an sproc that returns many records.  There is a date column however that can have the same value within this dataset.  Now what I want to do is filter these records to only include the latest data from this dataset.  How do I do this in T-SQL?  (I only want to see the 2/5 records below).

For example:

```
col A     col B     col C
AAAAAA    BBBBBB    2/5/2012
AAAAA2    BBBBB2    2/5/2012
AAAAA3    BBBBB3    2/1/2012
AAAAA4    BBBBB4    1/25/2012
AAAAA5    BBBBB5    1/25/2012
AAAAA6    BBBBB6    1/10/2012
```

I tried your solutoin Andreas, but I am getting the error now:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 74 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Here is a code snippet:

```
select *
from (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by [test_details_answers_expanded_view].[actual_date] 
    order by [test_details_answers_expanded_view].[actual_date] desc) rowno
    from 
    (
Select
    [test_details_answers_expanded_view].[event_log_id],
...
[test_details_answers_expanded_view].[actual_date],
...
FROM #TEMP_EVENT_LOG A  
JOIN [evolv_reports].[dbo].[test_header_rv] ON A.[event_log_id] = [test_header_rv].[event_log_id]
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fn_getTestSetupFormDetails](null, [test_header_rv].[test_setup_header_id]) AS [test_header]
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fn_getTestSetupFormDetails]([test_header].[test_setup_details_id], null) AS [test_details]
JOIN [evolv_reports].[dbo].[test_details_answers_expanded_view] ON
        [test_header_rv].[test_header_id] = [test_details_answers_expanded_view].[test_header_id]
    AND [test_details].[test_setup_details_id] = [test_details_answers_expanded_view].[test_setup_details_id]
Where  
(@TestHeaderCode Is Null OR [test_header].[test_header_code] = @TestHeaderCode)
   AND (@TestHeaderID Is Null OR [test_header_rv].[test_header_id] = @TestHeaderID)
) t
where rowno = 1
```

Can you tell what I did wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using row_number:

```
select *
from (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by [col c] order by [col c] desc) rowno
    from table
) t
where rowno = 1
```

Comment: Yes, but if I use the TOP statement, don't I need to know the number of records for it to select?  I want this to be a dynamic solution, where it will select the latest records regardless of the number of rows it is.

Comment: @salvationishere Misunderstood your question, please see my updated answer.

Comment: Andreas, can u check my revised description please?

Comment: @salvationishere You are just missing a paranthesis, on the row where you have `) t`, add `) t2`, i.e. after the alias `t` but before the where-statement.